# How to convert 2012-01-01T08:44:36+01:00 to datetime(yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss) in Java?

Tags: java

Can someone tell me how to convert this string   `2012-01-01T08:44:36+01:00`   to   `2012-01-01 08:44:36`   in Java?

Thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting ISO8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sometimes the simplest is best
>
> ```
> String s = "2012-01-01T08:44:36+01:00";
> // s2 = "2012-01-01 08:44:36"
> String s2 = s.substring(0,10) + ' ' + s.substring(12, 8);
> ```

This way may produce bugs with indexes, that may appeare, as in your example :-)
Also in case of some bad string you will spend a lot of time while finding the bug, because this simple way don't have any checks for input string.

Right indexes:

```
String s2 = s.substring(0,10) + ' ' + s.substring(11, 19);
```

If you want to work with date as with string, I prefer using RegXP:

```
    // You can parse your xml output using regXp:
    String s = "<root><date>2012-01-01T08:44:36+01:00</date></root>";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+)(T)(.+)([+-])");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + ' ' + matcher.group(3));
    } else {
        System.err.println("Bad date: " + s);
    }
```

**Speed testing:**

```
public class tempClass {

    static final String s = "2012-01-01T08:44:36+01:00".intern();
    static String formattedDate = null;
    static final int loop = 5 * 1000;
    static final String[] patterns = new String[]{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+01:00".intern()};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, InterruptedException {
        testSimpleWay();
        testRegXp();
        testSimpleDateFormat();
        testFastDateFormat();
    }

   private static void testRegXp() {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+)(T)(.+)([+-])");
        Matcher matcher;

        final long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();            
        for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
            matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                formattedDate = matcher.group(1) + ' ' + matcher.group(3);
            } else {
                System.err.println("Bad date: " + s);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Duration of RegXP: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStamp) + " ms.");
    }

    private static void testSimpleWay() {
        long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
            formattedDate = s.substring(0, 10) + ' ' + s.substring(11, 19);
        }
        System.out.println("Duration of Simple way: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStamp) + " ms.");
    }

    private static void testSimpleDateFormat() {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

        final long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
            try {
                formattedDate = simpleDateFormat.format((Date) DateUtils.parseDate(s, patterns));
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                System.err.println("Bad date: " + s);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Duration of SimpleDateFormat: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStamp) + " ms.");
    }

    private static void testFastDateFormat() {
        FastDateFormat fastDateFormat = FastDateFormat.getInstance("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        final long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
            try {
                formattedDate = fastDateFormat.format((Date) DateUtils.parseDate(s, patterns));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                System.err.println("Bad date: " + s);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Duration of FastDateFormat: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStamp) + " ms.");
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Duration of Simple way: 5 ms.
Duration of RegXP: 20 ms.
Duration of SimpleDateFormat: 114 ms.
Duration of FastDateFormat: 65 ms.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` class to format your date.

```
String value = "2012-01-01T08:44:36+01:00";
String date = null;
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
try
{
    Date d = format.parse(value);
    date = format.format(d);
}
catch (ParseException ex)
{
    System.out.println(ex);
}
return date
```

More info on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");  String time1=ft.format(time);                                         I tried with this but without success. It throws me an exception

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
try
{
    Date d = format.parse(value);
    this.value = format.getCalendar();
    this.length = value.length();
}
catch (ParseException ex)
{
    System.out.println(ex);
}`

Comment: Thanks Sunil for the answer. Is return from this code "d"? Because I need to return it as string? Will this be enough "d.toString();"

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat.format()` returns the `String`. Have a look at the code. I've updated it.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I can not use this "value" and "length" method.


I have as input parameter some string **time** (with T and +01:00) and I want it to convert it to date time. So how to do that? I do not want with time in this moment which I supose your method does.

Thanks

Comment: Got a bit confused. `value` variable is not a `Calender` type but a `String` type only. The above code will serve your purpose. Try it now

Comment: format.getCalender returns Calender object so this.value is Calender object and I can not compile my code until I set at the beginning of the class private Calendar value;  You can see it in attachment http://www.dodaj.rs/f/3f/tX/1OGbNIWb/string.jpg  that gives me an error

Comment: Hi, I can compile now but it gives me an exception java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2012-02-06T11:22:50+01:00"

Comment: What is T in between date and time??

Comment: I think it is remark for Time Zone. In database date is in correct format datetime 2012-02-06 11:22:50. Then system automatically creates in XML file this 2012-02-06T11:22:50+01:00 and I must get it out from there in format yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 0):

But remember that, SimpleDateFormat is not **thread-safe**.
You can use FastDateFormat from apache:
[FastDateFormat](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/time/FastDateFormat.html)

Usage:

```
// create a formatter that simply prints the year and month
FastDateFormat formatter =
    new FastDateFormat( "yyyy-MM",
                         TimeZone.getDefault( ),
                         Locale.getDefault( ) );
// output equals "2012-02"
String output = formatter.format( new Date( ) );
```

Parsing date:

```
FastDateFormat formatter = FastDateFormat.getInstance("yyyy-MM");
String s = "2012-01-01T08:44:36+01:00";
try {
    Object o = DateUtils.parseDate(s, new String[]{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+01:00"});
    // output equals "2012-01"
    String output = formatter.format(o);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.err.println("Bad date: " + s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I do not want currently time. I want time which I give as some parameter String time=2012-01-01T08:44:36+01:00; Does it can be done with this FastDateFormat?

Comment: You should parse your date first.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the simplest is best

```
String s = "2012-01-01T08:44:36+01:00";
// s2 = "2012-01-01 08:44:36"
String s2 = s.substring(0,10) + ' ' + s.substring(11, 19);
```

Comment: Thanks for response this is useful but my colleague says me that it is not good for the performance of the system because there will be a lots of dead strings in memory during the time

Comment: If you are worried about performance, using SimpleDateFormat or regular expressions creates many more objects and is much slower.